# During validation, using AJAX request to check DB. Form does not submit when true

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a form for an internal app where I am using client side validation. It's a whole nested javascript thing, with the last call being an AJAX request which checks to make sure there are two or less appointment books at the same time.

If it returns false (there are already 2 appointments booked), it triggers the error correctly. However, when it passes, the form doesn't submit, it just sits there. Does nothing. Well, at this point it pisses me off, but it doesn't do anything else.

```
$('#save-button').click(function(event){
    var firstAppointmentStartHour = 9;//No appointments before 9 am
    var lastAppointmentEndHour = 16;//No appointments after 4 pm
    if ($('#name').val() != ''){
        if ($('#address').val() != ''){
            if ($('#claim_number').val() != ''){
                if($('#vin').val() != ''){
                    if($('#plate').val() != ''){
                        if($('#appt_start').val() != ''){
                            var startDateTime = Date.parse($('#appt_start').val());
                            var startYear = startDateTime.getFullYear();
                            var startMonth = startDateTime.getMonth() + 1;
                            startMonth = (startMonth.toString().length == 1) ? '0' + startMonth : startMonth; //append a 0 if it is a single digit month
                            var startHour = startDateTime.getHours();
                            var stringStartHour = (startHour.toString().length == 1)? '0' + startHour : startHour; //append a 0 if it is a single digit hour
                            var startDay = startDateTime.getDate();
                            var startMinutes = startDateTime.getMinutes();
                            startMinutes = (startMinutes == '0') ? '00' : startMinutes;
                            var startTime = startHour + startMinutes/60;
                            var stringStartDate = startYear+'-'+startMonth+'-'+startDay+' '+stringStartHour+':'+startMinutes+':00';
                            if (startHour >= firstAppointmentStartHour){
                                if($('#appt_end').val() != ''){
                                    var endDateTime = Date.parse($('#appt_end').val());
                                    var endYear = endDateTime.getFullYear();
                                    var endMonth = endDateTime.getMonth() + 1;
                                    endMonth = (endMonth.toString().length == 1) ? '0' + endMonth : endMonth; //append a 0 if it is a single digit month
                                    var endHour = endDateTime.getHours();
                                    var stringEndHour = (endHour.toString().length == 1)? '0' + endHour : endHour; //append a 0 if it is a single digit hour (ie 9am)
                                    var endDay = endDateTime.getDate();
                                    var endMinutes = endDateTime.getMinutes();
                                    endMinutes = (endMinutes == '0') ? '00' : endMinutes;
                                    var endTime = endHour + endMinutes/60;
                                    var stringEndDate = endYear+'-'+endMonth+'-'+endDay+' '+stringEndHour+':'+endMinutes+':00';
                                    if(endHour <= lastAppointmentEndHour){
                                        if(startDay == endDay){
                                            if(endTime > startTime){
                                                if ( $('#email').val() != ''  || $('#phone').val() != '' ){
                                                    event.preventDefault();
                                                    $.ajax({
                                                        url: "/widgets/collision_center_appointment_calendar/check_overlap/" + stringStartDate + "/" + stringEndDate,
                                                        type: "get",
                                                        success: function(data){
                                                            if (data){
                                                                return true;
                                                            } else {
                                                                showError('**Only two bookings allowed at any time. Please adjust your start and end times**');
                                                                return false;
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                        error:function(){
                                                            $('#current_appointments').html('There was an error submitting your information... Please contact Team Systems.');
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                } else {
                                                  showError('**Please enter either a valid phone number or valid email address**');
                                                  return false;
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                showError('**The appointment start time must be before the appointment end time!**');
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            showError('**Start date and end date must be the same day**');
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        showError('**The last appointment of the day cant\'t end after 4 pm**');
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    showError('**Please enter an end date and time**');
                                    return false;
                                }
                            } else {
                                showError('**The first appointment of the day can\'t be prior to 9 am**');
                                return false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            showError('**Please enter a start date and time**');
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        showError('**Please enter a plate number**');
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    showError('**Please enter a VIN**');
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                showError('**Please enter a claim number**');
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            showError('**Please enter an address**');
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        showError('**Please enter a name**');
        return false;
    }
});
```

I don't do a lot of this sort of thing, and am very sure I've screwed up something simple.

Could any one of you fine folks help a brother out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning true to cause the form to submit after calling event.preventDefault() you need to call form.submit();

I'd suggest this (http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/) for further reading on the difference between return false and even.preventDefault(), but basically once you call preventDefault, calling return true will not cause the form to submit.

Also, I'd recommend looking into some validation libaries, like parsleyjs, it may save you some time / clean up your code a bit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback, it is appreciated. Works great! Will read up on your links, as a jr. dev I'm always looking for ways to improve...